# Clicking back after comment link closes app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When I follow a network link posted in comments, it successfully opens up the new post (in the app, not browser). When I click the back button to return to the previous post, it kicks me back to my launcher. Not cool.

It happens for any network links in comments, whether it's a generated "possible duplicate" or a manually pasted in link.

To be clear, this is **not** a crash. It just goes back to launcher as if the comment link clears the normal activity/task stack. When starting the app again from the launcher, it goes to the normal "feed" activity with no back stack.

Links in **questions and answers** work as expected.

To test, I'll comment below with a link, and add one here as well:

[Link in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222828/212780)

Nexus 5, Android 4.4, App version 1.0.15

Comment: [Link in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222828/212780)

Comment: Confirmed closing on Nexus 4, Android 4.4, App version 1.0.15. But in my case, the back stack is still there. Feed->MSO->This question->This question (from comment), closed after pressing `Back`, open again (directly goes to to MSO, not Feed).

Comment: This is still current in 1.0.27. Reproduced on a HTC One, Android 4.4.2. Except, in my case, when I reopen the app I'm back in the question list. I'd expect it to go back to the previous question, at least.

Answer (score 3):

This has been bugging me for weeks and I'm sorry I didn't get to it until now. It's fixed for the next update, 1.0.29.

Technical details:

The Q&A body links were working since we were manually intercepting them and handling them internally if we could before passing them to the OS. The links in the comments were not handled the same way, so they were instead being passed directly to the OS.

This allowed you the option to having us take care of it, which sent the link to our dispatcher that assumes the app isn't in foreground when you call it since it's almost always called from a SE link being loaded in another app.

I made comments have the same logic as bodies, so this doesn't happen anymore *and* you don't see a superfluous "What app would you like to open this link in?" pop-up when clicking on a SE link inside of the SE app.

Comment: Test message for push notifications.